# Python Code that just click on the element in webpage

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am new to Python, I was building a python code that downloads data from Website. However, I want a python code that just clicks on the column heading named "Line Item ID", so that upon clicking on that the data is auto sorted. So just want my python code to click on the column heading so the data is auto sorted. I have code like this but getting errors.
[Below is the column name on which I want to perform click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqkGt.png)

Below is my code : -

```
#layout selection 
    #driver.implicitly_wait(800)
    wait=WebDriverWait(driver,1000)
    wait.until(ec.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH,'//*[@class="text1"]//*[@name="layoutId"]'),'PPD Lineitem Milestone'))
    time.sleep(2)
    GTNlayout=Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="text1"]//*[@name="layoutId"]'))
    GTNlayout.select_by_visible_text('PPD Lineitem Milestone')
    time.sleep(2)

    GTN =driver.find_element_by_text('Line Item ID')
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    GTN.click()
```

I get the error below code

```
GTN =driver.find_element_by_text('Line Item ID')
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        GTN.click()
```

The error I get is as below: -
Error 1 -  File "C:Path.py", line 85, in 
GTN = Driver.find_element_by_link_text('Line Item ID')
NameError: name 'Driver' is not defined

> > > 

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QydlV.png)

Please help. I just need 1 line that goes and click the element "Line Item ID" on the webpage.

Is there any way that I can perform a click on the element "Shipment ID" on the web page? I again now tried below code but it is not working.

```
    GTN_Click = driver.find_elements_by_id("Shipment ID")
GTN_Click.click()
```

I had changed the code still I get a syntax error "Unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

Please help, "Shipment ID" is a column header all I want is my python code to perform a click on the column heading named "Shipment ID" so that the column gets sorted.

Comment: The error doesn't match the code. `Driver` should be `driver`. For the indent error, be sure you are not mixing tabs and spaces when doing indents.

Comment: its driver everywhere. I am not getting what u said

Comment: According to the error, on line 85: `GTN = Driver.find_element_by_link_text('Line Item ID')`  Are you still getting this error?

Comment: Yes I have now change the code to 
GTN_Click = driver.find_elements_by_id("Shipment ID")
GTN_Click.click()

still I get a syntax error pop up which states "Unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

Comment: In your source file, replace all tabs with spaces. That may highlight the indent issue. If you still get the error, post your full code so we can check it.